# How to programmatically get information in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-api

I'm developing an Eclipse Plug-in. 
I need to programmatically get both filepath and filename of the selected/active file in the eclipse editor.
Also need to programmatically add an existing file (located outside the project) to the project and then open it on the editor.
I'm a totally beginner with Eclipse, so complete solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You question is quite general, but this should clear things up a bit:

[Eclipse Plugin Development Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html)

About adding a file to the project, you have to read the documentation and find where eclipse handles projects. I think that if you have a reference to the project it should be easy.

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Your editor is most likely inheriting from `IEditorPart`, so you should be able to call `getEditorInput()`, which then may or may not turn out to be a `FileEditorInput`, for example. From there, you can get at the underlying details of the file.

For your second problem, you can use `IProject.create()` and then e.g. do an `IFile.createLink()` and use a local filesystem path, or copy the file using `IFile.appendContents()`.

Comment: editorPart returns a null value, and cannot advance from there.

Comment: @Crazy-Ivan: Are you calling `page.getActiveEditor()`? That one isn't reliable, depending on where you are coming from. Which editor do you concretely want to extend?

Comment: I have a JavaScript file opened in the editor, and I need to programmatically get it's filename and filepath. I have very few acknoledges in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution proposed in http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/97927/300308/#msg_300308?

Comment: had already tried but editorPart returns a null value, and cannot advance from there